# Using SingalR and Rabbit MQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, rabbitmq

My current configuration is:

Web App (JS) --> SignalR --> Service subscribed to RabbitMQ

I would like to add an intermediate step between "SignalR --> Service subscribed to RabbitMQ" such that I can do preprocessing of the data before passing it to SingalR and JS.

Is there a way to do it without using a dedicated service ? 
I would be interested in doing it in ASP.Net controller but I haven't been able to find a tutorial explaining how this can be done using ASP.Net and MVC such that messages would be pushed to Web App in real time.

Comment: It could go in your .NET SignalR hub class or inside your service subscribed to RabbitMQ. Why would it need a dedicated service?

Comment: Is .NET SignalR hub a class that persists on the server over multiple requests or is initiated every time a controller is called ?

Comment: I'm not sure. It may depend on how you're using it. You haven't shared any of your code, so you probably won't get any helpful answers here.

Comment: I recommend having a service that listens to the Rabbit queue, then when it receives a message it published it to SignalR.

Comment: I agree that service would be the best idea but I think its a bit of an overkill. Otherwise, I am not sure how you can make SignalR to listed to Rabbit